# Register media button on xamarin not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been trying to register to receive broadcast events from media button. I have successfully done in java and now I was porting it to Xamarin. But no matter what I try, its not recording anything. I have implemented receivers of all kinds, but for some reason, media button is just not working for me.

I have tried:

```
RegisterReceiver(new BroadcastReceivers.Media_Button(), new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionMediaButton));
```

I have tried:

```
ComponentName myEventReceiver = new ComponentName(this, nameof(Media_Button));
AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
myAudioManager.RegisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(myEventReceiver);
Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaButton);
mediaButtonIntent.SetComponent(myEventReceiver);
PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
// create and register the remote control client
RemoteControlClient myRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
myAudioManager.RegisterRemoteControlClient(myRemoteControlClient);
```

But no success.

Media button class:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Media Button Receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" })]
class Media_Button : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----------Detected media button--------------");
    }
}
```

Do note that the context being passed is from a service not and Activity

Comment: Have you also registered it in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, although I believe at compile time, its auto added when you add the "BroadcastReceiver" and "IntentFilter" attribute to the class

Comment: For giggles, I would go ahead and add it to your manfest, make sure that your continue to do `RegisterMediaButtonEventReceiver` (I'm assuming that is in your Activity `OnCreate` and you are launching that Activity before expecting to receive any broadcasts... Then using BOOT_COMPLETED your app will work for "normal users"

Comment: As I mentioned, i already added (just for giggles :) )
Though, I should mention that the context being passed its not an Activity, but a Service. WIll update the main post.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you build that ComponentName correctly. Could you try: `new ComponentName(this,Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Media_Button)))`

Comment: You are correct, i didn't build it right, however, i just get the action of the play button of my headset.. no volume button from the headset nor the device itself. Thanks for the component fix